# Trying to install auctex via package-install

Tags: init-file, auctex, package, package-repositories

I am trying to install `auctex` via `M-x package-install RET auctex`.

Unfortunately after a brief splash of
`Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443`,

I end up with the message
`https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex-12.1.2.tar:Bad Request`

On a different machine, this seems to work fine - I don't know where this is going wrong.

The top part of my `init.el` file currently reads:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))

  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
   ;;  For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))

(package-initialize)
```

Any ideas as to what I should try? This is Emacs 26.2 btw.

Comment: @Drew OK, trimmed it down a bit further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elpa seems to be having issues again. ([Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cdf48c/failed_to_download_gnu_archive/).)

Maybe try adding

```lisp
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```

to your config as [mentioned here](https://irreal.org/blog/?p=8243).

Comment: OK, this worked. Not very familiar with Elpa but it seems strange that the issues in the Reddit post occurred a month ago and it still hasn't been resolved.